# Unable to change forecolor of exception in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, colors, resharper

I am trying to fix an error in the [Resharper Sons of Obsidian Color scheme](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/resharper-son-of-obsidian) which highlights the Exceptions as the navy blue that is impossible to read. I have hunted through all the color combinations and cannot appear to isolate the color.

I also have VSCommands installed which I have attempted to disable all text processing to remove any highlights it may be doing.

[image]

Please let me know how to set this to a normal color.

Comment: I tried a dark scheme in VS once as it seemed cool, but after realizing that amount of colour changes to get it to look good and then finding some that you can't change, I gave up and reverted to the standard light scheme and just turned the brightness down on my monitor :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you see that color for all exceptions, or just for NotImplementedException?

By default, ReSharper styles those like "TODO" items (Tools | Options | Fonts and Colors | Resharper Todo Item).

If you don't want that, you can go to ReSharper | Options | Tools | To-do Items and remove "Not implemented" from the list.

Answer (score 1):

As Brian mentions, ReSharper categorizes `NotImplementedException` as a TODO item which can be found under the `ReSharper Todo Item → Foreground` entry in your color theme settings:

[image]